# Cannot unbind a certificate from a port (Windows 7)

Tags: wcf, ssl, ssl-certificate, ws-security

On Friday I successfully bound my certificate to port 443 using netsh.

Today I need to change the port, so I tried to 'unbind' it with netsh:

```
netsh delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443
```

The result is an error message

> The following command was not found: delete sslcert
>   ipport=0.0.0.0:443.

Confusingly the command is exactly as specified in the Microsoft documentation for netsh.

How do I remove a port binding so that I can rebind the certificate to another port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443
```

You were missing the `http` parameter.

Comment: Doh! Thanks. The MS documentation is a little confusing in this respect - it doesn't make it very clear that the http keyword is required.